# Existance of I-Projection

Tags: convex-optimization, information-theory, entropy

Let *X* be a finite set and A be a set of probability distributions on *X*.

Then KL-Divergence between two probability distributions P(x) and Q(x) $\in$ A  is
$$D(P(x)\vert \vert Q(x))=\sum P(x)Log(P(x)/Q(x))$$ for all x$\in$ X.

This KL-Divergence is a strictly convex function in P for a fixed distribution Q(x).

If A is a closed, convex set then the I-projection of Q(x) on A is
$$P^*= Arg(minD(P(x)\vert \vert Q(x))$$

Is $P^*$ always exit? If yes, then how can we prove this mathematically?

PS: I was reading "Information Theory and Statistics:A Tutorial by Csizer and Shield".In chapter number 3: I-Projection, it is written that since Kl-Divergence is a continuous and strictly convex function on a closed convex set A therefore $P^*$ is exist and is unique.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe you indirectly gave the answer to your question. Since the KL-divergence is strictly convex and the set you are minimizing over is convex and closed, it ensures the existence and uniqueness of $P^*$. You can find a proof in https://ai.stanford.edu/~gwthomas/notes/convexity.pdf.

Comment: According to proposition 2 : under these mentioned conditions atmost one minimizer will exist.So now my question is that is it possible to have no minimizer for I-projection?